# How do you transfer a binary file via Connect:Direct NDM?

Tags: unix, configuration, binary, transfer, mainframe

I'm trying to submit a binary file, in this case, an Excel file from my local server (Solaris server with Mainframe rehosting software) using Connect:Direct NDM to a destination server (Mainframe).

Here are the environment values I set:

```
SODETFL "DetailedReport.xls"
SODDETNDM "FIN.REPORT(+1)"
TDCOPTS ":DATATYPE=BINARY:XLATE=NO:STRIP.BLANKS=NO"
```

Here is the NDM configuration I use:

```
ASSGNDD ddname='SYSIN' type='INSTREAM'  << !
  SIGNON                                                                00260005
  SUBMIT  PROC=COPYFILE                    -                            00270005
              JOBNAME=JOB00001             -                            00280005
              PNODE=SERVER001              -                            00290005
              SNODE=NDMIDS                 -                            00300005
              SNODEID=(xxxxxx,xxxxxx)      -                            00310005
              HOLD=NO                      -                            00320005
              NOTIFY=CCACTD                -                            00330005
              NODE=,                       -                            00360005
    DSN1=${SODDETFL}                       -                            00370005
    DSN2=${SODDETNDM}                      -
    DCBINFO='dcb=(dsorg=ps, recfm=vb, lrecl=1504)'     -                                                                                                             00385005
              DISP1=NEW,                   -                            00390005
              DISP2=CATLG,DELETE           -                            00400005
              UNIT=BATCH                   -                            00410005
              SYSOPTS=${TDCOPTS}           -                            00440005
              AEFAJOB=PSIAPNB5
   SEL PROC WHERE (QUEUE=A) TABLE                                       00450005
   SIGNOFF                                                              00460005
```

I'm able to send text files via NDM all day long, no problems there.  However, it seems that binary is a bit more difficult.  When I try with the above configuration, I get the following error:

```
Completion Code  => 8
Message Id       => XCPS009I
Short Text       => Read buffer too small. Possibly src reclen > dest reclen.
Ckpt=>Y  Lkfl=>N  Rstr=>N  Xlat=>Y  Scmp=>N  Ecmp=>Y  Ecpr=>0.00 CRC=>N Zlvl=>1 win=>13 Zmem=>4
```

Can anyone shed some light as to how I can go about submitting a binary file via NDM?

Comment: Based on the message, the problem might be that the excel file has a very long
record length but the dataset you are trying to drop it into
has a shorter record length (i.e. 1504). Try increasing
the record length to something really big (e.g. 32767) then try again.

Comment: Interesting.  My XLS file is about 3 MBs.  What would be a suitable size to use instead of 32767 or is that the best option?

Comment: I still just guessing, but 3M is larger than the legal block size, you may have to 
resort to [spanned records](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.idad400%2Fspan.htm).
You may have to pre-allocate the file using IDCAMS since spanned records are VSAM datasets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the cuff...
Try changing RECFM=VB to RECFM=U and specify a BLKSIZE= instead of a LRECL=

This is really not all that different from how executable load modules are stored on the mainframe except you don't want the file to be a PDS dataset.  I'm not at my office right now and I think I have some examples of NDM that transmit load modules that I can look-up if this suggestion doesn't work but I think it will.

Give this suggestion a shot and if it still doesn't fly let me know.

Comment: What BLKSIZE should I specify on a file that's about 3 MBs big?

Comment: The optimal BLKSIZE depends on the device you are using.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, even though, this particular task in my project has not been addressed.  Thanks for the input!